# Why does gcc not warn when an enum or int value is passed on as a function's argument which is bool?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, gcc-warning

I have following code:

```c
typedef enum
{
    FOO,
    BAR,
    BAZ
} foo_t;

static void afunc(bool is_it_on)
{
    /* do the job */
}

int main(void)
{
    afunc(BAZ);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this code does not generate any warning message, even with `-Wall -Wextra` options given to the compiler. I have even tried with `-Wconversion` option, which took no effect because `bool` and `enum` seemed to be of same size for g++. (the size of `enum` type is not defined in specification as far as I know)

I have combed through gcc manual and found nothing about it.

Questions:

- Is there a way to force the compiler to generate a warning in cases like this?
- Or is it that this implicit casting is legal by c++ specification?

Compiler that I am using: gcc 4.1.2

---

**Editted**

Conclusion:

The only viable solution to this seems to define a new type to represent 0 or 1, and use it instead of `bool`.

The code would be like following, and g++ complains about type conversion:

```c
typedef enum
{
    FOO1,
    FOO2
} foo_t;

typedef enum
{
    MY_FALSE,
    MY_TRUE
} my_bool_t;

void foo(my_bool_t a)
{
}

int main(void)
{
     /* 
      * gcc generates an error.
      * error: cannot convert ‘foo_t’ to ‘my_bool_t’ 
      * for argument ‘1’ to ‘void foo(my_bool_t)’
      */
    foo(FOO1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because C++’ type system is only good for user-defined types, for built-in types it invariably sucks. Consequence of its C heritage.

Comment: Yes it seems so. I've decided to typedef a new type dedicated to represent only 0 or 1, and use it instead of bool which seems to be intended to express _true_ or _false_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, those implicit conversions are perfectly legal.

C++11 draft n3290, §4.12 *Boolean conversions*:

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a
>   prvalue of type bool. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false;
>   any other value is converted to true. A prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue of
>   type bool; the resulting value is false.

Warnings on these conversions (for arithmetic types) would probably lead to huge numbers of warnings all over the place, I don't think it would be manageable.

In C++11, you can use *scoped enums* to prevent that implicit conversion:

This fails to compile for lack of a conversion from `Foo` to `bool`:

```
enum class Foo { ONE };

void tryit(bool b) { }

int main()
{
    tryit(Foo::ONE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mat. If it is legal by C++ specification, I guess the only way to achieve what I want is to typedef a new boolean type just for the project so that the members of the project does not make mistakes such as the code snippet.

Comment: Sadly, gcc 4.1.2 does not seem to support 'scoped enums'. I guess I should resort to typedef solution, and it actually works.

Normally, you do not need that. But under some circumstances like you are refactoring other people's code, without this 'strict' type checking, you would be sorry. 

Maybe I should have used lint.

Comment: @orchistro: If possible, try to move on to a newer version on gcc (I know it's not easy...). gcc 4.1.x is quite an old branch.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I am more than willing to do that. I am the last one who does not welcome compiler upgrade. But the company does not allow it.

Comment: @orchistro: I was guessing that would be the problem, I rage because I am stuck at the 4.3 branch at work, so I can certainly empathize.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I was frustrated when I found out there was a "company standard compiler" and it was a 'stone age' compiler. I don't even seem to be able to make a dent in the company's policy which is made by a "standard group", lol. Anyway, work is just work :-)

Comment: Warnings are not constrained to only behavior which is illegal per the standards.  Warnings typically serve to highlight common mistakes or unintentional behavior.  Notably, this behavior still exists in GCC8 (no way to get a warning for bool/enum mis-comparison or assignment).